# How to visualize pgrouting query results in mapguide open source

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, mapguide

I would like to make a spatial query using postgis 2.0 and pgrouting 1.05 then visualize results in Mapguide open source.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you take a look Jo Cook's post on pgRouting + MapServer integration and adapt it for use in MapGuide Open Source

http://www.archaeogeek.com/blog/2012/12/24/pgrouting-and-mapserver/

EDIT: I've made a MapGuide-equivalent example

http://themapguyde.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/mapguide-and-pgrouting-shortest-path.html